# Onclick button doesnt fire when click

Tags: asp.net

this is code below that doesnt work, i try work with seperate solution with same database but this problem seems hard to solve. thanks in advance

```
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Register <span>Now</span></h2>
      <p>Ut possimus qui ut temporibus culpa velit eveniet modi omnis est adipisci expedita at voluptas atque vitae autem.</p>
    </div>
      <div class="php-email-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your ID Number" data-rule="minlen:8" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars" ></asp:TextBox>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
           <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" required="required" ></asp:TextBox>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email"></asp:TextBox>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
            <p>Register As</p>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="50px" Width="329px" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Italic="True">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Employee</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Customer</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mt-3">
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Address" Width="1119px"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
          <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Register" />
      <div class="text-center">
  
          </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</section>**strong text**
```

but this code below work, idk what the problem, its just same code with/without design

```
     <div>
     <div style="font-size:x-large; text-align:center">Register</div>
     <table class="nav-justified">
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">ID</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="243px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">Username</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="243px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">Password</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="243px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">Email</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="243px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">Register as:</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                     <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>Employee</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>Customer</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">Address</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="243px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 290px">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCC00" BorderColor="#FF3300" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF9900" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Register" />
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     <br />
     <a href="#myModal"  data-toggle="modal"class="book-a-table-btn scrollto">Log In</a>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <br /> 
 </div>
```

and these both codes share same aspx.cs buttons click function but it still doesnt fire and idk know why, i keep writing this because i cant submit questions otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this line of code:

```
<div class="validate"></div>
```

Try to avoid validation by changing CausesValidation attribute to false in the button element:

CausesValidation="false"